# How to use CMU pocketsphinx in own C++ project?

Tags: c++, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

When I want to use voice recognition in my program, do I need to install pocketsphinx on my Linux and include pocketsphinx.h in my code?

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedia:

> a group of speech recognition systems developed at Carnegie Mellon
>   University. These include a series of speech recognizers (Sphinx 2 -
>   4) and an acoustic model trainer (SphinxTrain).

Have a look here: https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/projectideas/

There are some very nice ideas and applications regarding this library.

For sure, in order to use the library you need to include the proper header file and possibly link with a shared library.